# How can I find a specific value in CollectView?

Tags: wpf

In wpf, a list was automatically created in the UI by referencing the value of the database through the CollectionView.

The creation structure of CollectionView is as follows.

```
 <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame BorderColor="Gray"
                               CornerRadius="5"
                               Padding="8">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="cardTouchCommand"/>
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Label x:Name="Label_Name" Text="{Binding cardName}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <BoxView Color="Gray" HeightRequest="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
                                <Label x:Name="Label_Memo" Text="{Binding cardMemo}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="Gray"/>
                                <Label x:Name="Label_SN" Text="{Binding cardSerialNumber}" IsVisible="false"/>
                                <Button Text="Delete" TextColor="Red" Clicked="cardSwipeCommad"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

I confirmed that the list was created normally by calling the value from the database.

I'm trying to create a delete function, but since CollectionView is created by copying StackLayout, I wonder how to call the value of the StackLayout when the Delete button inside the StackLayout is pressed.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Load the Parent of the Button

```
((StackLayout)sender).Parent.FindByName("Label_SN");
```

result, wrong cast option.

2. Query lamda

```
var labels = ((StackLayout)sender).Children.Where(x => x is Label).ToList();
```

result, can not find data.

I can't think of a way I can think of yet, so I haven't tried much.

If you have any good ideas, please advise.

Comment: What is the data type of the DataTemplate in your XAML?  That is what the `CollectionView` will contain.  Not visual elements, the actual items.  For sake of example, let us suppose it is of type class `Widget`.  You could just use LINQ.  Something like `collectionView.OfType<Widget>().Where(...)`  (fill in the `...` part)

Comment: Thankyou Joe!
It was effective when I implemented it again based on the answer.
Thank you very much.